# What does send_timeout option do on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver, keep-alive

What are the advantages and disadvantages of setting it low (10s) or high (60s) and how does it different from `keepalive_timeout`?

Comment: Do you really want apache tag?

Comment: Apache has similar options. they are the same.

Answer (score 10):

From [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

> Syntax:       keepalive_timeout timeout [header_timeout];
>   Default:  keepalive_timeout 75s;
>   Context:  http, server, location
>
> The first parameter sets a timeout during which a keep-alive client
>   connection will stay open on the server side. The zero value disables
>   keep-alive client connections.
>
> The optional second parameter sets a
>   value in the “Keep-Alive: timeout=time” response header field. Two
>   parameters may differ.
>
> The “Keep-Alive: timeout=time” header field is recognized by Mozilla
>   and Konqueror. MSIE closes keep-alive connections by itself in about
>   60 seconds.

---

> Syntax:       send_timeout time;
>   Default:  send_timeout 60s;
>   Context:  http, server, location
>
> Sets a timeout for transmitting a response to the client. The timeout
>   is set only between two successive write operations, not for the
>   transmission of the whole response. If the client does not receive
>   anything within this time, the connection is closed.

---

So when using `keepalive_timeout`, the browser does not have to make multiple connections, but uses the already established connection. This controls how long that stays active / open.

I would suggest that if you set the `send_timeout` small then your web server, it will close connections quickly, which will give more overall connections available to connecting hosts.

These parameters are most likely only relevant in a high traffic webserver, both supporting the same goal: less connections and more efficient handling of requests, either putting all requests into one connection (keep alive) or closing connections quickly to handle more requests (send timeout).

Comment: So what happens when the connection is closed? You still keep readin the page?

Comment: Typically this is a timeout so that means once no activity is seen. So its not like the connection only lasts for 60 seconds its that the connection will stay open for 60 seconds after that last bit of data comes through.